# http.get didn't get anything in nodejs

Tags: node.js, http, mongoose

There's the code in my project which try to get an access token from wechat.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var params = new URLSearchParams({
     grant_type: config.grantType,
     appid: config.appID,
     secret: config.appSecret
  });

  const url = config.wechat + '?' + params.toString();

  http.get(url, (res) => {
     console.log("haha");
     console.log(res);
     var rawData = '';

     if (res.statusCode != 200) {
        res.resume();
        console.error('statusCode:' + res.statusCode);
        return;
     }

     res.on('data', function (chunk) {
        rawData += chunk;   //buffer data if has
        console.log(rawData);
     });

     res.on('end', function() {
        try {
           console.log("haha");
           const accessTokenData = JSON.parse(rawData);
           console.log("access: " + accessTokenData);
           var newToken = new AccessToken({
                token: accessTokenData["access_token"],
                record_time: Date.now(),
                expires: accessTokenData["expires_in"]
           });

           newToken.save(function(err) {
                console.log("save error: " + err);
            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.error('parse error: ' + e);
        }
    });
  }).on('error', function(e) {
      console.error("get access token failed: " + e);
  });

   console.log("sadfdas");
});
```

what I want to do is getting access token from the api and store it into mongodb using mongoose. when I start node service on my local vagrant machine and access the route, there is **nothing** printed on the terminal and new record inserted into mongodb. So I don't know where's the problem, I'm sure that the url is right, which I have tested with postman. Please help me find the problem. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: `res.on('data', function (chunk) { += chunk;
        console.log(rawData); <
     });`
Do you see any print in this log?

Comment: no, even nor the "haha"  which should be printed firstly in the callback.

Comment: A good way to debug your code is using chrome debugger tools, Please install it by writing in the cmd `node --inspect <your_file>.js`. You can see it here: https://medium.com/@paul_irish/debugging-node-js-nightlies-with-chrome-devtools-7c4a1b95ae27